# Identity Service unknown variant certificateAuthority

Tags: azure, azure-identity

I'm trying to use identity service, but it says it fails with an unknown variant of certificateAuthority, when it expects none, sas, or x509.

Where does this certificateAuthority come from, should it be something else? If anything probably x509 in my case.

Here's a sample of the log:

```
.
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test systemd[1]: Starting Azure IoT Identity Service API socket.
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test systemd[1]: Listening on Azure IoT Identity Service API socket.
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test systemd[1]: Started Azure IoT Identity Service.
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - Starting service...
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - Version - 1.4.5
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - Provisioning starting. Reason: Startup
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- GET /keypair/device-id?api-version=2021-05-01 {"host": "keyd.sock"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-certd[37790]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- GET /certificates/device-id?api-version=2020-09-01 {"host": "certd.sock"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-certd[37790]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /parameters/algorithm?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "248", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /parameters/rsa-modulus?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "248", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /parameters/rsa-exponent?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "248", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /parameters/algorithm?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "248", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /parameters/rsa-modulus?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "248", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /parameters/rsa-exponent?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "248", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - Updated device info for EV-Charger-DEV-HW-00000001.
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - Provisioning complete.
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - Identity reconciliation started. Reason: Startup
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /encrypt?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "976", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - Could not reconcile Identities with current device data. Reprovisioning.
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- GET /keypair/device-id?api-version=2021-05-01 {"host": "keyd.sock"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-certd[37790]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- GET /certificates/device-id?api-version=2020-09-01 {"host": "certd.sock"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-certd[37790]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /parameters/algorithm?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "248", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /parameters/rsa-modulus?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "248", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /parameters/rsa-exponent?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "248", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /parameters/algorithm?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "248", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /parameters/rsa-modulus?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "248", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /parameters/rsa-exponent?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "248", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - Updated device info for EV-Charger-DEV-HW-00000001.
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - <-- POST /encrypt?api-version=2021-05-01 {"content-length": "976", "content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-keyd[37778]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [INFO] - --> 200 {"content-type": "application/json"}
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [ERR!] - Failed to provision with IoT Hub, and no valid device backup was found: Hub client error
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [ERR!] - service encountered an error
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [ERR!] - caused by: Hub client error
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [ERR!] - caused by: unknown variant `certificateAuthority`, expected one of `none`, `sas`, `x509` at line 1 column 398
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]: 2023-09-12T16:17:05Z [ERR!] -    0: <unknown>
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test aziot-identityd[95615]:    1: <unknown>
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test systemd[1]: aziot-identityd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 12 12:17:05 checkpoint-vm-test systemd[1]: aziot-identityd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

It says at the start it can provision, but for a later connection it fails.  I've looked at the config files and they seem right.  I've tried both manual and DPS with my certificate and key file.  I know the cert and key files work to connect to a device because I can connect to the device without an issue using the C SDK.

Comment: could please share the Azure IOT reference you used or the Azure IoT code with C

Answer (score 0):

The log mentions "Failed to provision with IoT Hub." The log includes the error message "unknown variant `certificateAuthority`, expected one of `none`, `sas`, `x509`.

- I Followed this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/quick-create-simulated-device-x509?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp) for Provision X.509 devices to Azure IoT Hub using a DPS enrollment [group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/tutorial-custom-hsm-enrollment-group-x509?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-ansi-c).
- In the Azure portal create an IoT Hub and an IoT device.

[image]

- Create Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service.

[image]

- Connect the IoT Hub with DPS by adding the IoT Hub to the Link IoT Hub.

[image]

- Create an enrollment group.

[image]

- Enable IoT Hub on the provision device.
- I enabled the certificate using this [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrbC2rbqjf0).

[image]

- Code Reference taken from [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/tutorial-custom-hsm-enrollment-group-x509?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-ansi-c#prepare-your-development-environment).

Output:

[image]